# Application doesn't launch after packaging up

Tags: wpf, wix, installation, windows-installer, package

I am in the middle of creating an application in which needs to be packaged up using a `WIX` installer package.

I am very new to using `WIX`, but I have spent time and effort to learn it so I can package up my `WPF` application.

Prior to learning `WIX`, I tried using a software called [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to help package my application up. It was great. I started of with a little application which worked fine. After, I tried using my actual `WPF` application, but what seemed to happen was, after including all the `dll`'s, and after launching the .exe file, the application didn't run at all. I tried on other machines within the office, but the same problem occurred. The application just didn't execute.

I then tried a simple `WIX` installer (without the dialogs). And I seemed to experience the same thing as the Advanced Installer did - It just didn't execute the `.exe` file.

What I tried (to test whether it was my application) was that I copied all my `dll`'s from my debug folder of my actual application, and pasted them into the Program Files on my `C:drive`. And that seemed to work on other machines as well as my own - which got me even more confused! I also made sure that the application build options were as follows;

```
Build Option: Page 

Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

Custom Tool: MSBuild Compile
```

Therefore, I am struggling to come to terms whether it is my application (whether its the `dll`'s or something missing within the actual app) **OR** whether I have been missing something within the actual installer (using `WIX`).

Any help, expertise or guidance would be much appreciated to help me understand what I am doing wrong - Like I say, I am new to the whole packaging so it might be something really silly that I am missing!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WIX is a packaging tool. It is just packed your application and put it into Client machine and does some other things which are not required here.

It is completely about your application configurations. Any application (WPF or Windows) .exe files required all reference assemblies should be available in client machine to execute. If you set Copy Local property to true, you need to ship the assemblies to application installation folder. If you set Copy Local property to false, you need to install all assemblies into client machine GAC folder.

It is always easy to ship the assemblies into installation folder than install it in GAC.

**Note:**

Framework also played major role in application packaging.

WPF applications are required .NET Framework 4.0 or at least .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 in client machine depends on Framework we are using to create applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vinoth. So what you saying is that I should copy the assemblies (dll's) in the clients machine as well as having the `.msi` WIX installer also? - Sorry if I don't follow properly! :S

Comment: We need to ship the assemblies along with exe while installing the setup. If you are having the assemblies into msi WIX installer, it will be shipped into client machine when we install the setup. No need to copy the assemblies separately.

Comment: Well, within the `TARGETDIR` I included the `.exe` file and also including all the `dll`'s also. Is this the correct way of achieving it?

Comment: Yes. But use Separate component for each files (assemblies, exe, etc).

Comment: Whats the benefit of using a separate component for each file?

Comment: Check "Step 2: Add files to your installer package" in this link.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/add_a_file.htm

Comment: It still doesnt seem to work after adding a component for each of my `dll`'s

Comment: @Vinoth Copy Local does not affect how assemblies need to be deployed. It is just an aid on the developer's machine to make it easier to run or debug. It _could_ also be used to gather dependencies in one place for packaging but where each dependency is installed to is an independent decision. Of course, all assemblies deployed to the app folder is nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), like WIX, is just a packaging tool also that does not affect how the installation runs. To install assemblies you have a different page, called "Assemblies", so you first need to add all the EXE and DLLs in Files and Folders page, then go to "Assemblies" page and add in the list the DLLs you need to install as assemblies.

From this new page, after you added the assemblies in the list, you can easily select (radio button) how they should install, i.e. private install, in your application folder next to the EXE, or machine install in GAC.

Please note that the Assemblies page is visible on Professional or higher project types, not in the free edition.

Regarding the separate components discussion from above. If you have a single component to install all files or separate components does not affect how the application runs. This is just a recommendation from Microsoft, in order to have a better design for your setup package.

Having a single component for each DLL will allow Windows Installer to trigger an automatic repair if one of those DLLs is missing or was altered. While as if you have a single component for all files will make Windows Installer trigger an automatic repair only if the [keypath (only one of those files) from that component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is missing or was altered, if any other file is missing or altered the repair will not be triggered when your application is launched.

In the following article you can find a little bit more details about [organizing components recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Bogdan - Thanks for the reply :). I am aware that all the WIX does is in essence, package everything into one manageable file. What I am struggling with is getting to grips and understanding it. I have put all my Dll's into seperate components. But Within my WIX, I feel as though I am missing something for it to not to load the application - but not sure what. Within the wixproj, am i supposed to reference my application?